How to use hasManyThrough with reference to morph table?
On laravel site with 3 related tables :
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            ...


        Schema::create('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->mediumText('content');
            $table->string('content_shortly', 255)->nullable();
            ...
            $table->foreignId('creator_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
            ...


        Schema::create('complains', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->morphs('model');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            ...



Field news.creator_id is ref to users table

In app/Models/User.php I have using hasManyThrough method:

    public function complainsOnNews()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Complain::class,
            News::class,
            'creator_id', // Foreign key on the news table...
            'model_id', // Foreign key on the Complains table...
            'id', // Local key on the complains table...
            'id' // Local key on the News table...
        );
    }

with request :
dd($this->profileUser->complainsOnNews);

I trace next sql :
SELECT `complains`.*, `news`.`creator_id`     AS `laravel_through_key`
    FROM `complains`
    INNER JOIN `news` on `news`.`id` = `complains`.`model_id`
    WHERE `news`.`creator_id` = 1

It is almost valid, but reference to complains.model_type missing some in some cases results would be wrong, it there some other models , not news
How that can be done ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.7",

Thanks in advance!
